# Is it worth unlocking potential only to merge?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I have kind of a Nino-centric team which is obviously led by a 5☆ Nino. I also recently obtained *another* Nino, but this time, she is a 4☆.

I have been trying to decide whether I should unlock the 4☆ Nino's potential for the sole purpose of merging with my existing 5☆ Nino or if I should just save the feathers to unlock another hero's potential later on, for instance, the heroes that are obtained through Grand Hero Battles as 3☆ or 4☆ only.

What I want to know is whether the benefit of having a level 40+1 5☆ Nino outweighs the benefit of unlocking the potential of a 4☆ hero into a 5☆ one. In general, is promoting for the sole purpose of merging worthwhile or cost-effective, or is it best to only merge heroes if I happen to get two of the same 5☆ hero?

For context, I have been managing to get quite a bit of feathers per Arena season (5k+). Combined with regular missions, I think I'm making roughly 7k feathers per month.

**UPDATE** - Just to give a little update on how my experience went

I did promote some heroes to 5*, but ended up sticking with my original Nino-centric team. Putting up a new solid team together is pretty hard, and I decided to focus on my main team while I don't have enought 5* heroes to make another arena competitive team.

I found that promoting the Askr trio was the most benefical choice to do with the feathers, and after that I went for the Super Nino, which is now +7, truly a powerhouse.

Comment: This seems a bit opinion based. Can you maybe reword it to ask about the pros and cons instead?

Comment: Maybe you guys would tell me "Hey, getting a 5* Nino isn't so rare. You could put those feathers to good use on another character instead."

Comment: I see a lot o people with 5* 40+4 or more heroes, and I start to wonder whether I should be investing more feathers, either by making my old heroes stronger and keeping a very centric team with few possible strategies, or investing in variety and broaden my rank of useful heroes. So far I have been giving priority to variety. I was focusing on having as many 5* heroes as I could.

Comment: People who have 40+ characters usually get lucky or have spent a lot of money. I have a couple +2 units, but they are hard to come by. I also have a handful of +1s. But nothing more than those. Weigh your options: Do you have any 4* characters you want to promote to 5* or are you in a figurative dry spell where no one is worth promoting such that boosting a Nino's stats by 2 is worth the 20k feather investment? For what it's worth, I've never promoted simply to merge and I've promoted roughly 8-10 units to 5* from 3-4*.

Comment: Good. I think this last comment of yours count as an answer. That's what I wanted to hear. If promoting simply to merge was kind of a waste or was a common practice (like the main way of getting 40+lot characters). If you mind posting an official answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ultimately depends on your personal preference, but there are some pros and cons to each side.

If you want to promote your 4☆ Nino solely to merge, then it would be best to stick to that plan and promote up any 4☆ Ninos you get in the future to merge with your "master" Nino. A level 40+1 Nino is nothing special. It's not until +4 or +5 where it really starts making a difference. However, you have to *really* be sure you want to commit to that. The feather cost of getting a +10 hero is astronomical, assuming you have to promote all 10 merged heroes, that's a minimum of 200,000 feathers. However, in the end, your Nino would be exceptionally strong and pretty tough, especially in the Arena.

On the other hand, the jump from a 4☆ hero to a 5☆ hero is quite drastic and, in many cases, unlocks unique weapons or third tier skills that are very useful. In your question, you mentioned Grand Hero Battle heroes, who never come as 5☆ units, requiring you to promote them to unlock their full potential. Of the past handful of these GHB heroes were Xander and Camus, two top-tier heroes whose true potential is only realized once they've been promoted to 5☆ so that they have access to their unique Distant Counter weapons. Dropping 20,000 feathers on these units as they come up is not a bad strategy, as it allows you to diversify your teams to handle different types of challenges.

The choice really boils down to whether you want to commit a **lot** of time and effort (and likely, money) to create a super Nino or use feathers on various units as you see fit to have an army of relatively good 5☆ heroes.

Comment: I won't put this as part of the answer, because it really is more of a comment, but I have a few merged units (Julia +2, Cordelia +1, Ike +1) and on **VERY** rare occasions, the 2-4 stat bumps they've received from merges have narrowly kept them alive (they were able to double or prevent being doubled, they had 1 extra point of defense or resistance to hang in there, 1 extra point of damage killed the enemy, etc). My point is, don't think that a 40+1 unit is *entirely* useless. It's just up to you.

Comment: Thank you for rewording the question. I couldn't have done better myself.

Comment: @Vemonus The +1 and +2 merges are usually the best because they upgrade the HP and the best stat for that unit.
I do agree that upgrade to 5 star is better than merging (and then slowly save-up for that 5 star merge)

Comment: @Nymph does it really? I always just assumed it was random. I'll have to keep that in mind

Comment: @Vemonus While hardly official the [Wiki](http://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Merge_Allies) seem to suggest it, while also my personal experience with merging 2 5stars Sheena (HP and Def)